# "Invalid Argument" Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, primefaces, invalid-argument

I've been receiving some strange errors when running my application, and was wondering if anybody can shed some light on them. I'm not able to post any pictures because I don't have a high enough reputation, so here's the text on the error messages:

*First Message:*

```
Error: Invalid Argument.
URL: https://[application-domain]/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces
Line: 21
```

*Second Message:*

```
Error: Unable to set the value of the property 'onload':object is null or undefined.
URL: https://[application-domain]/index.xhtml;jsessionid=[jsessionid]
Line: 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the code on the lines that have errors?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't seem to access the code for the first error, I believe it's JQuery code that's nested deep within the framework. For the second error, the first line is basically the XML version definition: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

Comment: From a quick search it could be a problem with your page `contentType`.  Have a look at the final post here and see if it helps... http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28558